# How can I insert a new column in a Dataframe with data produced via iteration?

Tags: python, pandas, append, iteration, concatenation

I am trying to insert a column called `Price Label` after the `Price` column in my AppleStore apps dataframe by iterating through the dataframe and appending a string ("Free" or "Not Free") to the apps with `price = $0.00.` As such the code I attempted is below

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    price = row.Price.replace('$','')
    if price == '0.0':
        row.append("Free")
    else:
        row.append("Non-Free")

df[column].append("price_label")   # in an attempt to add a header to column.
```

But then I'm met with the error message below. Could anyone tell me if there is a special way that pandas can concatenate a string to a data frame series/column? As always, I appreciate the communities help. You guys are the best.

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-191-c6a90a84d57b> in <module>
      6         row.append("Free")
      7     else:
----> 8         row.append("Non-Free")
      9 
     10 df.head()

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in append(self, to_append, ignore_index, verify_integrity)
   2580             to_concat = [self, to_append]
   2581         return concat(
-> 2582             to_concat, ignore_index=ignore_index, verify_integrity=verify_integrity
   2583         )
   2584 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\concat.py in concat(objs, axis, join, ignore_index, keys, levels, names, verify_integrity, sort, copy)
    279         verify_integrity=verify_integrity,
    280         copy=copy,
--> 281         sort=sort,
    282     )
    283 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\concat.py in __init__(self, objs, axis, join, keys, levels, names, ignore_index, verify_integrity, copy, sort)
    355                     "only Series and DataFrame objs are valid".format(typ=type(obj))
    356                 )
--> 357                 raise TypeError(msg)
    358 
    359             # consolidate

TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'str'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid
```

Answer (score 0):

```
price_label = []
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    price = row.Price.replace('$','')
    if price == '0.0':
        price_label.append("Free")
    else:
        price_label.append("Non-Free")
```

And Then

`df["price_label"] = price_label`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a new column with a default value, then update the rows, where the Price is 0:

```
df['price_label'] = 'Non-Free' # append a new column
df.loc[df['Price'] == '0.0$', 'price_label'] = 'Free' # set the price_label column, where the Price == 0.0$
```

The second row of the code filters by "boolean indexing":

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing

This article explains it in detail with examples:

https://appdividend.com/2019/01/25/pandas-boolean-indexing-example-python-tutorial/

Selecting by row and column index using loc(): https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-label

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`numpy.where(condition, x, y)`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to return the elements. Then you can use [`df.columns.getloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_loc.html) method the get the location of the `Price` column. Then you can specify the order of columns to rearrange them as required.

*Use this:*

```
import numpy as np

# --> make new column named `Price-Label`
df["Price-Label"] = np.where(df["Price"].eq("$0.0"), "Free", "Non-Free")

#--> get the location of `Price` column
price_col_loc = df.columns.get_loc("Price")

#--> Obtain the resulting dataframe by specifying the order of columns
#--> such that Price-Label column appear after the Price column
result = df[list(df.columns[:price_col_loc + 1]) + [df.columns[-1]] + list(df.columns[price_col_loc + 1:-1])]
```